# Generalized eigenvalue problem with non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Consider the following generalized eigenvalue problem with $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $m > n$.

$$[\lambda A-B]\mathbf{v} = 0$$

1. How can we find the "eigenvalues" $\lambda$?
2. Is it possible to transform this in a eigenvalue problem as $M\mathbf{v}= \mu I \mathbf{v}$ with $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You could try to use row reduction or something similar to find the values of $\lambda$ for which $\lambda A - B$ is not invertible, but unfortunately there is nothing so simple as solving a determinant for zero.

Comment: @Joppy Determinant of a non-square matrix?

Comment: Have you looked at simple explicit examples to get an idea of what it all means — e.g. $3 x 2$ matrices whose ranges are planes in $3$-space. Write down a couple of specific ones and try to solve for the “eigenvalues” directly by row reduction...

Comment: Multiplying each term by $A^T$ or $B^T$ produces square matrices and a generalized eigenvalue problem. You could also multiply by the pseudo inverse $A^+$ to produce a standard eigenvalue problem if $A^+A=I$

Comment: Where does this question from from? It's hard to help without knowing the background, context and motivation.

Comment: Thanks @greg. Very helpful. From my recent research I found that it is possible to multiply the equation for $A A^{T}$ to get $[(B^{T} B)^{-1} B^{T} A - \mu I]\textbf{v} = 0$. Ive read that for a tall matrix of real values, the pseudo inverse is $B^{+} = (B^{T} B)^{-1} B^{T}$. However, when I run pseudoinverse function in Julia language Im obtaining a result different from $(B^{T} B)^{-1} B^{T}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the goal is to perform a spectral analysis to evaluate the stability of a steady state solution.

Comment: Please add such details to the question itself. Questions should be self-contained. Readers should not have to read lengthy comment sections to understand what the motivation is.

Comment: About my previous comment. Analyzing the differences between the pseudoinverse and $(B^{T} B)^{-1} B^{T}$ results in Julia, it seems that its just a question of round errors. In fact the result of pseudo inverse function seems more precise.

Comment: If you're using Julia you might want to use the backslash operator instead of the pseudoinverse, since it can take advantage of any special structure (e.g. sparseness) of your matrix.